# ffmpeg convert mp3 to lower bitrate with existing mp3 tags

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to convert mp3 to lower bit rate without changing title,comment,artist and all other tags.

I am trying

> ffmpeg -b 64k -i "myfile.mp3" -ab 64k test1.mp3

When i am checking test1.mp3's file it haven't any tag , all tags are removed.

How to keep Tags while converting ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a newer version of ffmpeg. Current versions preserve ID3 tags when converting media files.

See the [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to builds for Linux, OS X, and Windows, or refer to a [FFmpeg compile guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

Comment: Newer ffmpeg version have video watermarking problem.This two thing can be solve with any 1 version ?

Comment: @user2708352 Ask a new question on [su] about the watermark issue ([so] is limited to programming questions). Make sure to search first since it is likely that there may already be an answer.

Comment: I updated ffmpeg version but still not working it removing all tags.

Comment: @user2708352: What version of ffmpeg did you update to? I suspect that it's still old.

Comment: ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on May 10 2013 15:14:14 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)

Comment: That's still about six months old. Current version is 2.0.1.

Comment: I am using ffmpeg 2.2.4 and I cannot for the life of me get it to copy any tag data across. I have tried -map_metadata 0 and about a zillion other methods it just won't work.

Comment: I managed to sort out my issue, I will post below on FrankieHmm's answer as it is relevant to that one.

Answer (score 0):

Append "-map_metadata 0" to your command-line on newer versions of ffmpeg to preserve tags.

Comment: After another hour of debugging, I have found that for my particular case, I had to specify the stream to copy from specifically, plus I had them in the incorrect. It appears that map_metadata takes the input/output in the opposite order.
My input file has 1 video stream at index 0 and 4 audio streams at 0:1, 0:2, 0:3, and 0:4.
The following command works for me, my specific goal was to copy the metadata from the stream that I was extracting:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -map 0:4 -acodec copy -map_metadata:s:2 0 output.m4a

Comment: Apologies, that command I pasted is incorrect, it was the non-working version. Might help someone for comparison purposes at some point. Here is the CORRECT version:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vn -map 0:4 -acodec copy -map_metadata:s:0 0:s:2 output.m4a

So it will copy the data from the 0:2 stream on the input file to the 0 index stream on the output (output is specified directly after map_metadata)